# Why are there so many CPU architectures: x86, x64, x87, etc...?

Tags: cpu-architecture

Is the main different just instruction set or something more essential??

Comment: You should be sure to understand the difference between the ISA (instruction set architecture, which is the language the processor understands) and the microarchitecture (the specific way the hardware is implemented).  In some cases, the ISA and microarch are tightly coupled, especially if aspects of the pipeline structure have to be exposed; some VLIW processors are like that.  In some cases, the ISA and microarch are decoupled with sophisticated decode logic, including modern x86 and (to a very limited extent) PowerPC.

Comment: Also, some architectural decisions will have more or less coupling between the microarch and the ISA.  For instance, a stack-based ISA would likely have a microarch that also uses a stack.  In some cases, you can't decouple them at all, like with dataflow and systolic array architectures.  The more coupling between the ISA and microarch, the harder it is to innovate and still remain compatible with old code.

Comment: "x64" is what Microsoft calls x86-64, aka AMD64.  x86 sometimes means specifically 32-bit x86, but can also be used to include all x86 modes and CPUs, including 64-bit mode, 32-bit mode, and I guess the obsolete 16-bit mode.

Comment: when I first started studying processor architecture these terms used to drive me crazy! This video should help, https://youtu.be/DSGlJvd5zjQ lots of pictures, analogies and like many are mentioning, x87 is a complete separate chip from the chip people often refer to as the cpu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

x86 is actually a shortened name of the 8086 processor series.  Yes, it is a specific instruction set; and usually indicates that it is a 32 bit system (bus size).  x64 usually has the same instruction set but is a 64 bit system (bus size).  I've never heard of the x87, but on a quick look; it appears to be a purely floating point co-processor broken out from the x86 architecture.  Another architecture that you'll see is the SPARC architecture which is a completely different architecture and instruction set from the x86 series.

Comment: So in a word,`instruction` and `length of registers`?

Comment: The majority of the differences will come between the instructions and the length of registers.  If you begin to walk further back in time you can get into the MMX, floating point differences, co-processors etc... But currently yes instructions and length of registers.

Comment: Does `x86-64` belong to x86 or x64??

Comment: x86-64 is the same as x64; it's an x86 processor with 64 bit.

Comment: x86-64 does *not* have the same instruction set as x86.  Among many other differences, SSE and SSE2 became core parts of the instruction set, and SSE 3 was added.

Comment: As the name x86-64 implies its x86 and more. Basically it can execute all x86 stuff but includes extras, extra instructions, extra registers  which make it easier to code for and more efficient. The x86 is a bit of an ugly beast, however luckily for us most is hidden away by todays high level langs and compilers.

Comment: @suroot your answer is incomplete, its a lot more than just having 64 regs.

Comment: Back in the old days, the x87 was a separate processor from the x86. You had to buy both. With the release of the [Pentium P5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P5_(microarchitecture)) in 1993, gone were the days of worrying about purchasing a math coprocessor; it was integrated _right into the die_ (while the [80486](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_80486) _did_ have the FPU integrated, you had to purchase the right model).

Answer (score 7):

Why are there so many CPU architectures?

In the early days, just getting a CPU working at all was a major accomplishment.
The early builders designed stuff with hardware as simple as possible, just to get something working --
they generally ended up with instruction sets that were very quirky.

Later builders, reluctant to force programmers to recompile all their software,
added new instructions but left the old instructions alone.
(This is commonly known as "compatibility barnacles").

People came up with dozens of innovations that made CPUs easier to program or faster or better in some other way -- index registers, address registers, data registers, wider address registers, wider data registers, link register, interrupts, single-instruction subroutine CALL, single-instruction effective address calculation, pipelining, single-instruction multiply, VLIW, etc.
Many of these innovations required at least new instructions, if not completely updated instruction sets.
(Other innovations, such as cache, made CPUs faster without changing the instruction set at all, so the new CPU still runns all the old software unchanged).

IBM's policy in 1982 was to require at least 2 sources for all parts.
(Even today, many manufacturers are reluctant to buy "single-source parts").
To convince IBM to buy Intel processors,
Intel licensed their designs to AMD, a licensed second-source manufacturer.
The lawsuit over this license was very public.

The long legal [lawsuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amd#IBM_PC_and_the_x86_architecture) between Intel and AMD worried many CPU designers.
When some CPU designer came up with some new innovation,
rather than incrementally adding a few instructions to the x86 instruction set or some other pre-existing instruction set -- risking getting sued --
CPU designers felt more comfortable coming up with completely different instruction sets
to showcase even relatively minor innovations.

In several cases, two different people come up with conflicting innovations -- each one is clearly superior to the old CPUs before either one was invented, but it doesn't seem possible to build a CPU that supports both innovations at the same time.

There are still today [many different kinds of computer architectures](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4185/what-are-different-types-of-computer-architectures).

Comment: That's the actual answer.

Answer (score 2):

The instruction set may differ slightly; however, the key differences are the length of registers, and as a result the amount of addressable memory.

```
x86 has 32 bit registers 
x87 is a floating point extension of x86
x64 has 64 bit registers
```

See also:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X87

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X64

Comment: The x87 wasn't an "extension" of the x86, but was a separate chip.  When the x86 processed an ESC instruction, it would fetch the following byte and, depending upon the contents of that byte, it would perform read or write cycles to memory while ignoring the data bus.  The x87 would watch the data bus and some control signals and, if it saw the x86 process an ESC instruction, it would watch the data bus to see what it was supposed to do; when appropriate, it would put data on the bus during the x86's write cycles so its data would get stored in RAM.

Comment: Starting with the 80486, the floating point functions were moved onto the same chip as the main processor, but the design of the x87 architecture was predicated upon its being a separate chip.

Answer (score 2):

There are also families of CPU's so the difference can be significat. Just think of [RISC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_instruction_set_computing) computing or [stack-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_machine) CPU's.